# Migrations are pending error while everything is up to date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a strange issue with migrations. The last migration file is: `20190826113704_add_percentage_account_to_contacts.rb`.

The timestamp in `schema.rb` is `ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_08_26_113704)`.

So you would say everything is up to date. When I start the server and go to the site I get the `Migrations are pending` error. So when I run `rails db:migrate` I get an error `relation "study_agreements" already exists` which is correct, there are no migrations pending.

So how can I solve this?

Comment: Look at the migration status with `rails db:migrate:status`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your database reflects that migration is loaded but somehow the entry in *schema_migrations* either got deleted(accidentally or through migration rollback).

Steps to solve this issue:

1. Identify the migration(migration number) from *db/migrations* where *study_agreements* relation was introduced. Let's say it is *1234*
2. Now manually create an entry in *schema_migrations* table in your DB. For example in MySQL you can do "INSERT INTO schema_migrations (version) values(1234)".

Another solution is: Run *rake db:migrate* after commenting the *change* or *up* method of your migration in which *study_agreements* relation was introduced.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you have already have a table in DB and you have down migrated file in your migrate folder. you can do 2 things here:

1. Run `rails db:schema:load`
   OR
2. If you don't have data in your db then run `rails db:reset`

Comment: rails db:schema:load did the trick for me. Thanks